# purrr map: index a vector with elements of a list

Tags: r, loops, functional-programming, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to change my code from base-r for-loops to purrr. I want to access a variable number of elements from an integer vector for a list with k elements.

I have a vector

```
set.seed(1)
subset_from<- sample(c(-20,2), size= 60, replace =T)
```

And I have a list named "chosen_rounds" with 14 elements, each element is an integer vector of variable length.

```
k <- 14 # number of elements in the list chosen_rounds 
k_small <- sample(sample(1:15, k, replace = T))
chosen_rounds <- map(k_small, sample, x=1:30, replace=T)
```

Now, I want to access the elements "chosen_rounds" of my vector "subset_from" and calculate their mean for each of list element, i.e. I want a vector with 14 elements, each of which is the mean of a subset (a weighted subset, i.e. some elements of subset_from may occur multiple times in this subset) of the vector subset from.

For the first instance, this would be:

```
mean(subset_from[chosen_rounds[[1]]])
```

which is -12.

I have played around with lmap, imap or map2, but everything threw errors or returned lists will all elements = NULL.

This code works

```
chosen_rounds[1] %>% unlist() %>% subset_from[.] %>% mean
```

but I have not figured out how to generalize it such that I do not have to specifically index chosen_rounds, but that it automatically iterates over each element of the list.

Thank you very much for any ideas how I can iterate over each list element.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It takes a detour over naming the chosen_rounds vector.

```
list_names<-names(chosen_rounds) <- seq_along(1:k)   

recalled_means <- map(list_names, ~ mean(subset_from[unlist(chosen_rounds[[.x]])] )  )
```